# How works perforated acoustic wood panels?

Tags: acoustics, room-treatment

Perforated acoustic wood panels seem to flourish everywhere in public places nowadays. I saw them installed as room separators, on walls (with or without an air gap), and even on a classroom ceiling.

I wonder which physical principle they are based on. And how to calculate the hole size and spacing, the wood panel thickness and the distance to the rear wall (probably related to the desired damping frequency?)

[image: Acoustic wood panels]